# How to reference a specific button, with dynamically created buttons that have the same name?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically create buttons depending on the amount of entries in a excel file.

Each row of buttons needs a open, edit, favorite and remove buttons.
I'm trying to make the corresponding favorite button change color depending if the entry is in the favorite list, and the color toggle if it's pressed. I know how to add or remove a entry to the favorite list with a button, but I can't figure out how to reference a specific button to make it change color.

I've tried some "magic" with the lambda function and command (I don't fully understand it), so I can do the logic and reference an entry when a button is pressed, but I can't figure out how to reference when that specific button is pressed since their names are the same and I can't define which button should then change color and to my best effort I couldn't find the missing information in the documentation, googling etc...

edit:
pasted a smaller example version of the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
buttons = []

list_of_favorites=['tofu']
list_of_recipes=['tofu','burger','salad','taco']

amount_of_recipes=len(list_of_recipes)


def fav_pressed(recipe_ref):
    recipe_specific=list_of_recipes(recipe_ref)
    if recipe_specific in list_of_favorites:
        list_of_favorites.remove(recipe_specific)
        fav_btn.configure(fg_color='black')
        
    else:
        list_of_favorites.append(recipe_specific)
        fav_btn.configure(fg_color='yellow')



for recipe in range(amount_of_recipes):

    #set the initial color of a button
    dynamic_color='black'
    if  list_of_recipes[recipe] in list_of_favorites:
        dynamic_color='yellow'
        
    #create a button   
    fav_btn = tk.Button(root, text='★',fg_color=dynamic_color, command= lambda recipe_ref=recipe: fav_pressed(recipe_ref),)  
    btn.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```

NOTE: I'm really new to programing.

Comment: Rather then providing whole code, it is preferred just to provide [mre] that would help us to analyze at the specific part of the code and better identify the problem.

Comment: Please reduce this code to a [mre] so we can help you better identify and fix the problem

Comment: This code won't run. `fg_color` isn't a valid option. Plus, `btn.pack` won't work because you've named the widget `fav_btn`. And there are other errors. Make sure your example actually runs.

Comment: Also, see [ask]. Do a preliminary research at first. There are many possible methods, such as storing button objects into a list or specifying the command callback with the ```configure()``` after creating the button. (For the second case, you can reference the button in the closure(lambda).)